# Mongo shell search by field value returns no result, although field exists

Tags: mongodb

A search without a query returns some documents. Then I try to query one of those documents by a field value, and the query returns nothing:
`

```
> db.packageData.find( { },{data : 0} ).limit(2).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "RB#0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml_1666644148902",
        "filename" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml",
        "p_uid" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723",
        "tunnelPackageId" : NumberLong(116723),
        "userId" : "RB",
        "contentType" : "CAMERA_XML",
        "length" : 13652,
        "uploadDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.902Z"),
        "forwardDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.903Z"),
        "forwarded" : false
}
{
        "_id" : "TOP#0122SS01CT1_20221024_164225_00116726_3.jpg_1666644148991",
        "filename" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164225_00116726_3.jpg",
        "p_uid" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164225_00116726",
        "tunnelPackageId" : NumberLong(116726),
        "userId" : "TOP",
        "contentType" : "THUMBNAIL_IMAGE",
        "length" : 34556,
        "uploadDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.991Z"),
        "forwardDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.991Z"),
        "forwarded" : false
}
> db.packageData.find( { "filename" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml" },{data : 0} ).pretty()
>
```

Thanks for any ideas!
`
I tried escaping a "." in the filename value, but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

you did something wrong, see output I got for your data:

```
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.coll.insertOne({
...         "_id" : "RB#0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml_1666644148902",
...         "filename" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml",
...         "p_uid" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723",
...         "tunnelPackageId" : NumberLong(116723),
...         "userId" : "RB",
...         "contentType" : "CAMERA_XML",
...         "length" : 13652,
...         "uploadDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.902Z"),
...         "forwardDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.903Z"),
...         "forwarded" : false
... })
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedId" : "RB#0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml_1666644148902"
}
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.coll.find( { },{data : 0} ).limit(2).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "RB#0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml_1666644148902",
        "filename" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml",
        "p_uid" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723",
        "tunnelPackageId" : NumberLong(116723),
        "userId" : "RB",
        "contentType" : "CAMERA_XML",
        "length" : 13652,
        "uploadDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.902Z"),
        "forwardDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.903Z"),
        "forwarded" : false
}
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.coll.find( { "filename" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml" },{data : 0} ).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "RB#0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml_1666644148902",
        "filename" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723.xml",
        "p_uid" : "0122SS01CT1_20221024_164223_00116723",
        "tunnelPackageId" : NumberLong(116723),
        "userId" : "RB",
        "contentType" : "CAMERA_XML",
        "length" : 13652,
        "uploadDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.902Z"),
        "forwardDate" : ISODate("2022-10-24T20:42:28.903Z"),
        "forwarded" : false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking dododo, much appreciated.  of course, I'd be thrilled if somebody pointed out specifically what is wrong with my query, but at least now I know I am not crazy and will press on along the same lines.  Thanks!

Comment: there is nothing wrong with query you provided. I simply copied all your code and it works. You can check it yourself. There is something different here, maybe different db or server